# Using a single channel on a 2 channel DAC + Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, dac, i2s

I am planning to use an external DAC + amplifier combo to output mono sound from my microcontoller. The ouput from the amplifier would be connected to a single speaker

```
DAC : PCM5102
AMPLIFIER : PAM8019
```

The sound data from my mcu is MONO format and both these chips support 2 channels.The I2S data will be mono.

My question is how do I just use the single channel on them? What do I do with the OUTL pin (on PCM5102) and LIN, LOUT-P and LOUT-P pins(n PAM8019)? Do I simply connect them to ground?

[image: PCM5102]

[image: PAM8019]

I've never worked with audio before so all this is new to me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1: Don't hook outputs to outputs, unless they're specifically designed for it.  2: Ground is an output.

Comment: I would connect the left channel between the two chips as normal (I assume there's a recommended circuit in a datasheet someplace).  Then I would leave the left channel output pins of the PAM8019 open.

Comment: I assume you meant leaving the right channel output of PAM8019 open. But would that not induce noise?